# Is it possible to have another layout in my main layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, imageview

Is it possible to have another layout in my main layout?
Such that i can set my imageview in another layout.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a child layout from your Java code and then use addView() method.
For example:

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.addView(new LinearLayout(this));
```

Comment: Possible to add a @layout file instead? Already have been created.

Comment: Sure, you can use LayoutInflater class.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take a look at this blogpost.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Is there another way, the code is not in an xml but a class file.